# How to implement multiply chain requests and return the results in one observable?

Tags: angular

I need to implement the following process:

1. To make the request A and to check the specific field - "N" in the result.
2. if N is true then to make second request;
3. I need to have one observable which will include the results from this two requests;

Here example of what i do:

```
 this.reservation = this.rest_angular.all('reservations')
                    .get(route.params.id, 
                    { expand: 'beddingConfig,agentSummary,providerTitle' })
                   .switchMap(agent => this.users = 
                    this.rest_angular.all('users').get(agent.agentId));
```

But it is not possible to paste the: this.reservation and this.user into one observable;

**When i check "this.reservation" by subscribing, i get the data from last request only!**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

```
getData()
{
return this.rest_angular.all('reservations').get(route.params.id, { expand: 'beddingConfig,agentSummary,providerTitle' })
    .switchMap(agent => return this.rest_angular.all('users').get(agent.agentId)
    ,(reservation, user)  => [reservation, user]);
}

//you use 
getData.subscribe([reservation,user])=>{
   console.log(reservation,user)
}
```